# Boolean algebra: Why does the equation hold?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I want to show that $$\bar y\land (x\lor z)\land (\bar x \lor  \bar y) = \bar y\land (x\lor z)$$

I have done the following:  \begin{align*}\bar y\land (x\lor z)\land (\bar x \lor \bar y) &=\bar y\land \left [(x\lor z)\land (\bar x \lor \bar y)\right ]\\ & =\bar y\land \left [\left ((x\lor z)\land \bar x\right )\lor \left ((x\lor z)\land \bar y\right )\right ] \\ & = \bar y\land \left [\left (\left (x\land \bar x\right )\lor \left (z\land \bar x\right )\right )\lor \left (\left ( x\land \bar y\right )\lor \left (z\land \bar y\right )\right )\right ] \\ & = \bar y\land \left [\left (0\lor \left (z\land \bar x\right )\right )\lor \left (\left ( x\land \bar y\right )\lor \left (z\land \bar y\right )\right )\right ] \\ & = \bar y\land \left [\left (z\land \bar x\right )\lor \left ( x\land \bar y\right )\lor \left (z\land \bar y\right )\right ]\end{align*} Is everything correct so far? How can we continue?

Comment: This may help a bit $$(x\land\bar y)\lor(z\land\bar y)=(x\lor z)\land\bar y$$ Then this with $\bar y$ at the front just combines to give the same thing

Comment: From an intuitive viewpoint, the last OR on the LHS is superfluous, because $y$ already has to be false for $\bar{y}$ to be true, which makes $\bar{x}\lor\bar{y}$ true.

Comment: Do you mean the following? \begin{align*} \bar y\land \left [\left (z\land \bar x\right )\lor \left ( x\land \bar y\right )\lor \left (z\land \bar y\right )\right ]&= \bar y\land \left [\left (z\land \bar x\right )\lor(x\lor z)\land\bar y\right ] \\ & =\left [\bar y\land \left (z\land \bar x\right )\right ]\lor\left [\bar y\land(x\lor z)\land\bar y\right ] \\ & = \left [\bar y\land \left (z\land \bar x\right )\right ]\lor\left [\bar y\land(x\lor z)\right ]\end{align*} Ho could we continue? @JohnDoe

Comment: Could you explain that further to me? @AdrianKeister

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show $$\bar y\land (x\lor z)\land (\bar x \lor  \bar y) = \bar y\land (x\lor z)$$

Intuitively, the left hand side of this says that $y$ must be false (because we have $\bar y \land \dots$), and so $(\bar x \lor \bar y)$ is a tautology—it is always true. So we can rewrite this as $\bar y \land (x \lor z)$, which is exactly the right hand side. So they are equivalent statements.

More rigorously,

$$
\begin{align}
\bar y \land (x \lor z) \land (\bar x \lor \bar y) \\
=\bar y \land (\bar x \lor \bar y) \land (x \lor z) && \text{commutativity} \\
=\bar y \land (x \lor z) && \text{absorption} \\
\end{align}
$$

The ‘absorption’ law we just used is a standard identity but if you really want proof,

$$
\begin{align}
x \land (x \lor y) \\
=(x \land x) \lor (x \land y) && \text{distributive} \\
=x \lor (x \land y) && \text{idempotent} \\
=(x \land 1) \lor (x \land y) && \text{identity} \\
=x \land (1 \lor y) && \text{distributive} \\
=x \land 1 && \text{annulment} \\
=x && \text{identity} \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Do you mean the following? \begin{align*}\bar y\land (x\lor z)\land (\bar x \lor  \bar y)&=\bar y\land (\bar x \lor  \bar y)\land (x\lor z)\\ & =\left [(\bar y \land \bar x) \lor (\bar y \land \bar y) \right ]\land (x \lor z)\\ & = \left [(\bar y \land \bar x) \lor 0 \right ]\land (x \lor z) \\ & = (\bar y \land \bar x) \land (x \lor z)\end{align*} How could we continue?

Comment: Check my edited version. $(\bar y \land \bar y) = \bar y$, rather than $0$.

Comment: I got it!! Thank you so much!!! :-)